# How news headlines bring in Python web scrolling

Tags: python

I tried to use the html on the page to call up the news title, but nothing keeps being made on that list called rank1. What is the problem?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page1 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://sports.media.daum.net/sports/team/epl/253").read()
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1,'html.parser')
rank1 = soup1.find("ul",{"class":"list_newsinfo"})
print(rank1)
```

and this is the site's html I tried
[image]

Comment: Don't look at the DOM inspector, look at the page *source*. It probably doesn't contain that section and loads it after the fact using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The section you are inspecting is dynamically loading after the page has loaded. This is why you should use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org)

```
pip install selenium
```

Following code will load the elements you are looking for. It uses PhantomJS web driver. You can [use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-headless-chrome-firefox/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://sports.media.daum.net/sports/team/epl/253"
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
a = soup.findAll("ul", {"class": "list_newsinfo"})
```